# WP плагин, как получить данные введенные при его настройке?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Создаю свой WP плагин, есть необходимость в папке с плагином wp-content/plugins/simple-widget/ 
получить данные в файле **settings.php**.

Как в settings.php получить данные из базы, сохраненные в настройках самого плагина simple-widget/**simple-widget.php**?

simple-widget.php - исполняемый файл плагина/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. нужно в файле settings.php получить значения переменных title и name, которые были заданы в настройках плагина, чтобы далее работать с данными.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Файл settings.php, лежащий в папке с палгином (с разными вариантами вывода):

```
<?php
echo get_option('name');

$name = get_option('name');

echo $name;
?>
```

Сам плагин (файл simple-widget.php):

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: A simple Widget
 * Description: A widget that displays authors name.
 * Version: 0.1
 * Author: Bilal Shaheen
 * Author URI: http://gearaffiti.com/about
 */

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_widget' );


function my_widget() {
register_widget( 'MY_Widget' );
}

class MY_Widget extends WP_Widget {

function MY_Widget() {
    $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'example', 'description' => __('A widget that displays the authors name ', 'example') );

    $control_ops = array( 'width' => 300, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'example-widget' );

    parent::__construct( 'example-widget', __('Example Widget', 'example'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
}

function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    extract( $args );

    //Our variables from the widget settings.
    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );
    $name = $instance['name'];
    $show_info = isset( $instance['show_info'] ) ? $instance['show_info'] : false;

    echo $before_widget;

    // Display the widget title 
    if ( $title )
        echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

    //Display the name 
    if ( $name )
        printf( '<p>' . __('Hey their Sailor! My name is %1$s.', 'example') . '</p>', $name );


    if ( $show_info )
        printf( $name );


    echo $after_widget;
}

//Update the widget 

function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = $old_instance;

    //Strip tags from title and name to remove HTML 
    $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
    $instance['name'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['name'] );
    $instance['show_info'] = $new_instance['show_info'];

    return $instance;
}


function form( $instance ) {

    //Set up some default widget settings.
    $defaults = array( 'title' => __('Example', 'example'), 'name' => __('Bilal Shaheen', 'example'), 'show_info' => true );
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); ?>

    //Widget Title: Text Input.
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e('Title:', 'example'); ?></label>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
    </p>

    //Text Input.
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'name' ); ?>"><?php _e('Your Name:', 'example'); ?></label>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'name' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'name' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['name']; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
    </p>


    //Checkbox.
    <p>
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php checked( $instance['show_info'], true ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_info' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'show_info' ); ?>" /> 
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_info' ); ?>"><?php _e('Display info publicly?', 'example'); ?></label>
    </p>

<?php
}
}
require_once('settings.php');

?>
```

Пожалуйста, помогите получить данные title и name в settings.php

Comment: Автор, советую более глубоко выучить синтаксис php, понять, что такое ООП, чтобы понять, как работать с переменными, так как вопрос ближе к php, а не к WordPress.  В вашем примере нету функции, которая записывает\сохраняет настройки, тоесть сейчас их нужно добавлять в табличке `wp_options` вручную только. Также, при использывани `get_option()` советую устанавливать значение по умолчанию, если таковой опции не найдено в БД, намного легче будет понять в некоторых моментах, где проблема.

Comment: Если я правильно понял хотелку, то подход не верный. Никакие настройки не должны "браться из файла". Они должны браться из базы. Дефолтные, соответственно, должны туда прописаться сразу при активации плагина. И удалиться при его удалении (не деактивации!)

Comment: Я имел ввиду из базы, просто описывал, что настройки мне нужны из файла конкретного плагина, пытался объяснить, что хочу получить и в итоге всех запутал.